# Haskell - Grouping duplicate tuples from a list and making them unique by snd

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates, tuples, grouping

I have a list of tuples

```
[(1, "aa"), (1, "bb"), (2, "aa"), (3, "cc"), (4, "cc"), (1, "aa")]
```

and I want to convert it into this

```
[(1, "aa"), (2, "aa+1"), (1, "aa+2"), (1, "bb"), (3, "cc"), (4, "cc+1")]
```

where sequence doesn't matter.

Each element is unique by `snd`

I was thinking something along the lines of this could work

```
identifier :: [String]
identifier = map (\ x -> (\ a b -> b ++ show a) x "+") [1, 2 .. ]


unUniqueNumbered :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)]
unUniqueNumbered = zipWith (\b a -> (fst a, snd a ++ b)) identifier


uniquifySND :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)]
uniquifySND theList = concat $ groupBy ((==) `on` snd) theList
```

The problem was, `groupBy` only groups adjacent duplicate elements.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Hint: use `sortBy`

Comment: There's already a definition of `Ord` for `String` that will do what you want.

Comment: @assembly.jc Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

[sortOn](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.0/base-4.12.0.0/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) did the trick.

```
sortOn snd theList
```

Now duplicate elements are adjacent so `group` can work like usual

Thanks @assembly.js for the hint!